# How to change attribute of elements in a set cpp

Tags: c++, set

I defined a set and it's operator:

```
class CompareStateId {
    public:
    bool operator()(State *_state1, State *_state2)
    {
        if (_state2->getId() == _state1->getId()) return true;
        return false;
    }
};
set<State*, CompareStateId> consideredState;
```

Then I want to change the value of state in this set:

```
set<State*, CompareStateId>::iterator it = consideredState.find(_state);

if( it != consideredState.end()){
    if(_state->getStepCount() < *it->getStepCount()){ // [Error] request for member 'getStepCount' in '* it.std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<_Tp>::operator-><State*>()', which is of pointer type 'State* const' (maybe you meant to use '->' ?)
        *it->setStepCount(_state->getStepCount());
    }
}
```

I don't want to erase and reinsert for because of some reasons.
How to change attribute of elements in a set cpp?

Comment: operator precedence… also, don't write `if (cond) return true; return false;`, write `return cond;` instead.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant Your comment on `if` is off-topic, but essentially anything that would be found in an introductory tutorial or standard document is on-topic for this site.

Comment: @Potatoswatter my comment on `if` is entirely appropriate.

Comment: @ThuyNguyen [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence)

Comment: It doesn't matter if a question is 'too basic' or 'too fundamental', it only matters if it's asked well.  This one appears to be.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker um nope? I thought SO was not a "teach me the programming language" site…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to operator precedence,

```
*it->getStepCount()
```

is the same as

```
*(it->getStepCount())
```

what you are looking for is:

```
(*it)->getStepCount()
```

Similarly, you need to use:

```
(*it)->setStepCount(_state->getStepCount());
```

Answer (score 1):

Your error is unrelated to the `const` requirements of `std::set`.

The `*` operator has lower precedence than the `->` operator. Instead of `*it->setStepCount` you need `(*it)->setStepCount`.